# How to Find out if Eclipse is running in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging

There are a lot of question/answers about how to detect from the code if Eclipse is running in debug mode; but I can't find any source the describes how the user can find out if Eclipse is running in debug mode or not.  I have examined Eclipse while running an application to find out if it is running the application in debug mode or not, and I can't find any source explaining this.  I have also gone through the output messages in console, and again there is nothing that indicates if the application is running in debug mode.

So, can someone please tell me how I can find out if the application that is running in eclipse is running in debug mode or not.

Comment: I run huge apps which take a long time to start.  Now, if I have already started such an app, and don't remember whether I have started the app in run or debug mode, then I have to stop the app, and restarted in debug mode.  However, if there is a way to know if it is already in debug mode, then I won't have to restart the app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Switch to the "Debug" perspective and look at the Debug pane. If it looks like this, you're not debugging:

[image]

And if it looks like this, you are debugging:

[image]

Comment: Thanks providing me the answer Matt.